# Are self-similar measures a.c. with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu_p$ be the self-similar measure on the Borel sets of the unit interval $[0,1]$, determined by
$$
\mu_p(E)=(1-p)\mu\left(f_0^{-1}(E)\right)+p\mu\left(f_1^{-1}(E)\right),\qquad 0<p<1,
$$
where
$$
f_0(x)=\frac x 2\qquad {\rm and}\qquad f_1(x)=\frac x 2+\frac 1 2.
$$

Is $\mu_p$ absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure? My intuition tells me that should be the case, but I haven't been able to prove it.

If the answer is yes, what can be said about the corresponding Radon-Nikodym derivative? For instance: where is it continuous? where is it differentiable?

Comment: Your intuition is wrong, unfortunately. That measure is concentrated on the set of real numbers having a frequency of $p$ of 1-bits, and $1-p$ of 0-bits in their binary expansion, and that set has Lebesgue measure zero.